# Convert a list of words and save in json file

Tags: node.js, json

I would like a list of words that I save in a json file by a request from an api.
The words are without quotation marks and commas,
for example:

`name1 name2 name3`

I want to save them in the following format in the json file

```
[
    "name1", 
    "name2",
    "name3"
 ]
```

the existing files can be overwritten. However, no duplicate words should be saved

With my code, it doesn't really save what I want

`"name1" "name2" "name3"`

this is my code

```
const data = JSON.parse(jsonObjekt);

data.forEach((follower, i) => {
  const element = data.data[i].to_name;
  var nameArr = JSON.stringify(element, null, 2).split(' ');
  fs.writeFileSync('names.json', JSON.stringify(element, null, 2).split(" ")+',', { 
  encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'a+' })

})
```

This is the jsonObjekt i get

```
{
  "total": 94,
  "data": [
  {
    "login": "username",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "login": "username",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "login": "username",
    "name": "name3"
  },
...
}
```

Comment: what is name1 name2 name3? a string?

Comment: console.log(jsonObjekt) and print it here please

Comment: @charly1212
`{
  "total": 94,
  "data": [
  {
    "login": "username",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "login": "username",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "login": "username",
    "name": "name3"
  },
...
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
const fs = require('fs')

const jsonObjekt = {
    "total": 94,
    "data": [
    {
      "login": "username",
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "login": "username",
      "name": "name2"
    },
    {
      "login": "username",
      "name": "name3"
    }]}
let data = [];

jsonObjekt.data.forEach((follower, i) => {
    data.push(follower.name)
  })

fs.writeFileSync('names.json', JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: when i request the api i get this error 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"
  
this is my complete code
https://jsfiddle.net/fr04xb3w/

Comment: unless you post your full jsonObjekt it is hard to guess

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/1Ss4Dmkz

this is what i get from jsonObjekt

Comment: ok but there is no name. do you want from_name?

Comment: Yes, i have edited the code in my question. i want to get all to_name and save them

Comment: then write data.push(follower.to_name). if you really get your jsonObjekt from your api this code works. if not you have a problem with you api call and it does not return the json structure you provided